How do we rigorously eliminate $r^n$ and $\log r$ terms in a Fourier series (solving the polar Laplace equation) which is bounded at infinity?
In my PDE module, the general solution to Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 T=0$ in the plane (in polar coordinates) was shown to be $$T(r,\theta)=A_0+B_0\log r+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(A_nr^n+B_nr^{-n})\cos(n\theta)+(C_nr^n+D_nr^{-n})\sin(n\theta).$$ The lecture notes now claim that, in boundary value problems where solutions have to be bounded at infinity, the $\log r$ and $r^n$ terms are inadmissible, so their coefficients must be zero. For the logarithmic term this makes sense, as $\log r$ is indeed unbounded; but I am struggling to justify the other part of the claim to myself. For example, momentarily letting $\theta=0$, and looking at the boundary value problem $$\lim_{r\to\infty}r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=0,$$certain series solutions such as $$T(r)=\frac1r\cos\theta+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{r^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}\cos(n\theta)=_{\theta=0}\frac{\sin(r)}{r^2}$$satisfy the boundary condition (in this case, provided $\theta=0$) just fine. Now of course this isn't exactly a counterexample to the lecture notes' claim, since when $\theta=\pi$ I suddenly have a hyperbolic function on my hands; but I can't see how to dismiss the possibility of counterexamples such as these occurring. It certainly does seem believable that, given any choice of coefficients $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$ in the general solution, there exists some $\theta$ causing the solution to be unbounded; but I have no idea how to prove this (if it is even true).

We also have to rule out a really annoying thing like $B_0\neq 0$ but somehow the log term cancels with the necessarily divergent series term at infinity. But one kind of glib answer would be, by using this heuristic we derive solutions which work and then we tend to have uniqueness of solution theorems, which should settle the matter - assuming you've proven uniqueness of coefficients for these Fourier series. This course always was a bit handwavy though

Has to hold for all $\theta$.

After learning some complex analysis over the summer, I now have the tools to solve this, as a simple application of Liouville's theorem.
I claim that if $T:\mathbb R^2\setminus D(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ (where $D(0,1)$ is the unit disc) is given by a series of the form $$T(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_nr^n+B_nr^{-n})\cos(n\theta)+(C_nr^n+D_nr^{-n})\sin(n\theta),$$ and is bounded at infinity, then for each $n$, $A_n=0$ and $C_n=0$.
Proof:
First, we can rewrite $$T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(A_n\cos(n\theta)+C_n\sin(n\theta))r^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(B_n\cos(n\theta)+D_n\sin(n\theta))r^{-n}$$ and note the second term is bounded, so that we may WLOG assume $B_n=D_n=0$.
If $T$ is bounded, so is $$T^*(r,\theta):=i\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_n\sin(n\theta)-C_n\cos(n\theta))r^n.$$
Now, we may write $z=re^{i\theta}$ and view $T+T^*$ as a function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$. This is also bounded by assumption, and we have:
$$T+T^*=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_nz^n-iC_nz^{n}),$$
so that $A_n=C_n=0$ by Liouville's theorem.
